# Netbean PHP code completion navigation without using arrow keys

Tags: netbeans

I tends to use arrow keys to navigate throw list of code hinting suggested by Netbeans. Problem is this happens too often that I feel it's much better to use some keys under my hands (which is not far to reach).

Is there any other keyboard for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well, you want arrowed keys/browsing tools closer to your left hand? I see some solutions.

- Remap a keyboard to have some of the keys you don't use act as arrow keys. If you have no such keyboard, you could buy one that has extra buttons, like a multimedia keyboard or a gaming keyboard Gaming keyboards are especially designed to be programmed by the user, so they should be simple to use.
- Buy an advanced mouse with extra buttons, like a gaming mouse. For example, I think some have two wheels, on of which has that left-right motion to side-scroll. You could one wheel as an actual wheel, and the other as "arrow keys".
- Buy an external numeric keypad. Place it wherever you want, and either turn num lock off to use the existing arrow keys (4, 8, 6, 2) or remap it to your tastes, and have fun. Something like this: like this: http://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16823328008

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I found remapping works best for me. BTW, I see a shortcut using KP UP, What does KP stand for?

Comment: Uhm. Keypad? As in, numeric keypad? I think? Unless for some reason it's something from here. xD http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kp